# How to determine if device supports widevine classic only?

Tags: android, drm, widevine

So far I am able to detect if device supports any kind of widevine version, but I need to be sure that device doesn't support classic (even when it does support widevine modular).

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a **try-catch** statement in the code that tries to use classic then catches the exception and uses widevine instead? I'm not familiar with widevine, but just a thought?

Comment: You want to disable classic after making sure they have a version of widevine, correct?

Comment: I need to be sure that they don't have classic. No matter if they have modular or not. Newer devices has modular but not classic.